# Trying to connect to a PCI Modem

Tags: modem, pci

I hope someone can offer some advice, I'm very new to linux/Debian so I'm sure it is probably me doing something stupid.

I have just installed Debian on a pc that was running windows xp.  But am stuck on getting the pci modem to work.  I had hoped to be able to telnet to the modem port and test if the caller id was still working and if so somehow get this information into openHAB.  But I'm stuck on connecting to the modem.

Typing **# lspci -vv** returns the following, think this is the modem bit

```
04:01.0 Communication controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. Device 10b4 (rev 89)
        Subsystem: Digitan Systems Inc Device 9300
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Step                                                                                ping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort                                                                                - <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 64
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5
        Region 0: Memory at febf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Region 1: I/O ports at ec00 [size=8]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot                                                                                +,D3cold-)
            Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
```

But can't seem to connect via telnet, I have tried the following ports /dev/modem, /dev/ttyS0-3, /dev/ttyACM0

Hope someone can help as I'm really stuck.

Modem is a Zoom/Modem V.92 PCI 3025C - https://www.zoomtel.com/graphics/datasheets/dial_up/3025_2758.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, those cheap small ones were known as "[Winmodems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winmodem)" so the "driver" also does most of the heavy lifting, so it's not as simple as customizing a UART. Good luck; a lot of links are going to be dead. Something like this might work https://github.com/dspinellis/dgcmodem but it's going to need an older kernel.

Comment: :O I though modems are no longer used. I was using `winmodems` with linux long, long time ago and as I remeber they may need "firmware" from Windows or special program to work.

Comment: [Linux Winmodems Support](http://www.linmodems.org/)

Comment: [What are Winmodems](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Winmodems-and-Linux-HOWTO-1.html) on [The Winmodems-and-Linux HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Winmodems-and-Linux-HOWTO.html#toc1) from year 2001.

Comment: If `/dev/ttyACM0` exists on your system, it might be that the kernel is in fact detecting the modem. Run `dmesg -H` as root and scroll through the listing: does it mention anything about TTY devices, or anything else that seems relevant? What does `setserial -g /dev/tty[AS]*` say? You cannot communicate with modem devices using `telnet`: you'll need a serial terminal program such as `minicom` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!  

I can't see any mention ttyACM0 in dmesg -H.  The tty devices are the serial ports shown here:  


`[    3.239596] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    3.260170] 00:02: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    3.280896] 00:03: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    3.301514] 00:05: ttyS2 at I/O 0x4e0 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    3.322157] 00:06: ttyS3 at I/O 0x4e8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A`

Comment: If I type the address code of the modem card ** dmesg | grep -iC 3 "febf0000" ** I get the following.  the address code is from # lspci -vv.  Does this help?

`pci 0000:00:1c.4: PCI bridge to [bus 03]  
pci_bus 0000:04: extended config space not accessible  
pci 0000:04:01.0: [14f1:10b4] type 00 class 0x078000  
pci 0000:04:01.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfebf0000-0xfebfffff]  
pci 0000:04:01.0: reg 0x14: [io  0xec00-0xec07]  
pci 0000:04:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot  
pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04] (subtractive decode)`

Comment: I have also just installed minicom and when I open it, I get cannot open /dev/modem.

I'll have a look at winmodem drivers, but the links are so out of date and I'm very inexperienced with this.  If anyone has any more information I would be very very appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: Still working on this!  Just ran the cnxtinstall.run on http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/downloads-installer.php and get the following.   `ERROR: No supported devices were detected on your system. It is possible
that you have a modem which is not based on a HSF or HCF Conexant chipset.
It is also possible that the driver is not available for your architecture
or you have a device with a different PCI/USB ID than the drivers expect.`

Comment: Looks like I have found the driver, as my card has the PCI ID `10B4` on here [link](http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hcf/) but the install fails.  But that's no surprise as I'm using  Debian amd_64 and the install is 32-bit.  Would anyone have any advice if it's possible to get this to work?? Thanks